# "argument 'sql' cannot be null" when including "Go" in EF DbMigration

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

When adding the SQL server [`GO command`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) to a `DbMigration.Sql("GO ...")` call causing the `Update-Database` entity framework method to throw the exception "argument 'sql' cannot be null".

Remove the `GO` and the migration fails because the next SQL statement is creating a trigger, which must be on its own.

Comment: GO is not an SQL Server Statement

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Comment: @Steve I see your point, but it *is* filed under `SQL Server Utilities Statements` which can undoubtedly lead to confusion. Your first comment might have been better clarifying that it's a command, not a statement - it could be interpreted to mean that it's not supported at all by SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry it was just a little note on the question text. (Now fixed). I feel the need to write that comment because trying to send a string containing a GO command to SQL Server using ADO.NET triggers an exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found absolutely no info on this issue, so thought SO might benefit.

From reading around, I found that in SQL Server `GO` must be followed by a newline, so I think the root cause to this issue has to do with that and how EF parses the SQL before sending to the DB.

The way I solved the issue was discovering an optional parameter to the `DbMigration.Sql(sql, suppressTransaction=false)` method.

`suppressTransaction` forces the sql query to be separate to the rest of the migration (usually this is all called as one transaction). Hence removing my need to use `GO` at all.